# Charaters/Bytes count and File size on Windows properties difference

Tags: filesize, word-count

I have a txt file got generated through PHP script. File character count is shown correctly as 3999 bytes/characters when i checked through my script.

When i checked the same content by copy&paste into MS-Word, still it was showing 3999 characters/bytes(with spaces).

However, when i looked at the windows property of the same txt file, it shows the size as 4.17 KB (4,278 bytes).

I am just wondering, what could be the reason for such big margin of difference when i had looked at it. If someone can clarify this, it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your script may have been saved as UTF-8 format which has a 2 byte *marker* at start of file. Unicode characters may also consume more than 1 byte. Did you also count trailing whitespaces and new line (CR+LF) characters?

Comment: In my code, am not counting new line, but whitespaces yes. So, I just want to know how do i ensure the number of bytes OR characters are same in all the respects. Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering..whether slack space allocation on the file would also cause these bytes difference. Not sure but.

Comment: The byte file size *is* the number of total characters in the file. This include both visible characters and invisile characters (whitespaces). UTF-8 marker characters won't be visible on Unicode text editor. Slack space doesn't take effect here, since the file size is 4278 bytes and is not multiple of 512 bytes. So it's the actual file size, and it doesn't include slack space due to sector/cluster based disk storage.

Comment: ok thanks for that. Basically, i will upload these txt files which has 4,000 bytes and below to that into iTunes Connect, where iTunes connect doesn't accept texts that contain more than 4,000 bytes. Whenever, i have file with 3,865 or something, windows show it as more that 4 KB. So, thats where the problem is.