# two bytes too much using File#length()

Tags: java, file, io, size

I was trying to read a text file that I wrote with Mac's textEdit (Plain Text) by means of a simple java program. My code could be summarised as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    long length = file.length();         // in my case 615

    int i = 0;
    while(i < length) {
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fis)) {
                // NOTE: fis.available() == length
                reader.skip(i);
                System.out.printf("Character at position %d is %d\n", i, reader.read());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem now is that there are only 613 characters in my file, whereas `file.length()` return 615. The last two characters read are `-1` as can be seen in the output from this method.

My question now is: Where might those 2 extra bytes come from? Can I just subtract 2 from `length` to get the number of ASCII-characters?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your code doesn't involve ASCII at all. `InputStreamReader`: [The charset that it uses may be specified by name or may be given explicitly, or the platform's default charset may be accepted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html). If you believe the file contains text encoded in ASCII (unlikely), you should pass that to the InputStreamReader constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be too obvious: textEdit converted "..." to some unicode character, making the ASCII-assumption invalid.

Answer (score 0):

There are often end-marker character (or at begining).

First one: it seems to be text (from text editor ?).

Second: you get binary content.

filesize is the size of the file on the OS. It can depend on type of file an d OS. For example, unicode files have BOM at start.

real size for you is when you get it with FileInputStream (in a byte array).

I then think 613 characters are enough and exactly what you get.

see this: [Charaters/Bytes count and File size on Windows properties difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616164/charaters-bytes-count-and-file-size-on-windows-properties-difference)

it helps ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand. Do you mean there are some unicode characters in my text? What do you mean with: "you get binary content"?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a 2 characters [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of your file. Some editors do this automatically. Try and open the file with a hex editor to see the 2 characters.

Comment: I did and there was nothing added in the front, but I already discovered my mistake. TextEdit converted "..." to some unicode character, making the ASCII assumption invalid.